# How can I get images into my li from a wordpress gallery with a loop

Tags: html, wordpress, loops

I'm making a WordPress website and I created everything outside of it. Now i'm getting it all together but I'm pretty new to this. I would like to create a Wordpress loop to get images from a gallery, replacing the img tag.

------- Edited -------

So there was a small change in the design but same problem. I need to get the images from a gallery in Wordpress to fill two slideshows with the same images.

```
                        <div id="slider1">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="mySlides1">
                                <img src="images_1.jpg">
                                </li>

                                <li class="mySlides1">
                                <img src="images_3.jpg">
                                </li>

                                <li class="mySlides1">
                                <img src="images_2.jpg">
                                </li>
                                <li class="mySlides1">
                                <img src="images_4.jpg">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
 
                        <div id="slider2">
                            <ul>
                               <li class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="images_1.jpg">
                                </li>

                                <li class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="images_3.jpg">
                                </li>

                                <li class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="images_2.jpg">
                                </li>
                                <li class="mySlides2">
                                <img src="images_4.jpg">
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

I edited the question

Comment: I need a little more information to help. What do you want to do with the images after you loop through and get them? Do you need the image src saved or the whole img element? Also, what do you want to replace the img tag with?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I basically created a slideshow through css + js, and I want the client to be able to change the images on the post/page related to this slideshow. So I would like to get imgs from the post or a gallery in it. They most be inside a li tag with a specific class because I’ve two slideshows in that page. 
Hopefully this will be the info you need!

Answer (score 0):

As the question has been updated, I'm updating my answer to fit the new requirements. Basically, I've just added a parameter to the **_GetSSImages()** function. This allows you to pull the images from a specific slideshow, assuming that the **class=""** is unique for each slideshow. If not, then I would need to adjust the structure of the function.

*----Original answer with updated code:*

There are few things I don't know, such as how you intend to display the list of images from the slideshow, or how the client will edit this list.

However, you can use the javascript function below to grab all of the image src attributes from the slideshow HTML based on what you've shown here. The function returns an array of all src attributes so you can call it wherever you need to in your code to get the list.

```js
function _GetSSImages(slide) {
  var slideEls = document.querySelectorAll(slide),
      slideImgs = [];
  
  for(var i = 0; i < slideEls.length; i++) {
        if(slideEls[i].querySelector("img").src != null) slideImgs.push(slideEls[i].querySelector("img").src);
  }
  
  return slideImgs;
}

var slideShow1 = _GetSSImages("mySlides1"),
slideShow2 = _GetSSImages("mySlides2");
```

```html
<div id="slider1">
    <ul>
        <li class="mySlides1">
        <img src="images_1.jpg">
        </li>

        <li class="mySlides1">
        <img src="images_3.jpg">
        </li>

        <li class="mySlides1">
        <img src="images_2.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="mySlides1">
        <img src="images_4.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="slider2">
    <ul>
       <li class="mySlides2">
        <img src="images_1.jpg">
        </li>

        <li class="mySlides2">
        <img src="images_3.jpg">
        </li>

        <li class="mySlides2">
        <img src="images_2.jpg">
        </li>
        <li class="mySlides2">
        <img src="images_4.jpg">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So there was a small change in the design but same problem. I need to get the images from a gallery in Wordpress to fill two slideshows with the same images.


I edited the question

Comment: @mpb I have updated my answer to work with multiple slideshows. Based on your updated code, each slideshow **<li>** has separate classes (*mySlides1, mySlides2, etc.*), and as long as that is the case my answer should work.

Comment: Hey @EssXTee thanks! I'm gonna give it a try. English is not my native language so sorry for any confusion. So the client will edit this list on the wordpress backend adding or removing images from a gallery created in a specific page.